# Android HttpURLConnection POST Request with image/jpeg

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send image in POST request with `HttpURLConnection`. I have next code:

```
String i3 = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
ByteArrayOutputStream i4 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
i4.write(("--" + i3 + System.lineSeparator()
        + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + I1.this.i2 + "\"; filename=\"" + I1.this.i2 + ".jpg\"" + System.lineSeparator()
        + "Content-Type: image/jpeg" + System.lineSeparator()
        + "Content-Length: " + String.valueOf(i2.this.i1.length) + System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes());
i4.flush();
i4.write(i2.this.i1);
i4.flush();
i4.write((System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator() + "--" + i3 + "--").getBytes());
i4.flush();
i4.close();
HttpURLConnection i5 = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(myUrl).openConnection();
i5.setRequestMethod("POST");
i5.setDoOutput(true);
i5.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
i5.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + i3);
i5.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(i4.toByteArray().length);
i5.connect();
OutputStream i6 = i5.getOutputStream();
i6.write(i4.toByteArray());
i6.flush();
i6.close();
System.out.println(i5.getResponseCode() + " " + i5.getResponseMessage());
i5.disconnect();
```

But when I'm trying to get response code/message of connection application throws me an exception:

> 07-28 12:15:00.722: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on
>   Connection{123.456.789.012:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=123.456.789.012
>   cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)

Maybe problem is my post request is bad or having syntax errors? Can you help me and say what's wrong, please.

---

I tested this code on Java application on windows! The result of request is `200 OK`. Conclusion: Something wrong with android! But I still don't know what concretically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! This ugly strings `System.lineSeparator()` need to be replaced with old kind `\r\n`! Great.